# Configure touchpad

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, multi-touch, synaptics

I bought a new laptop and installed Ubuntu 14.04. I can use touchpad and I have synaptics driver installed but I'm not able to:

- Turn on and off touchpad (laptop has a function key which doesn't work in Ubuntu)
- Configure gestures (like 2 fingers down to scroll, etc.)

Synaptics driver is supposed to be installed, these are installed packages listed:

- xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-lts-trusty
- xserver-xorg-input-synaptics

The command `xinput list` lists these devices (there's a pointing device but I think is a device of lenovo pointing style, not the touchpad):

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:400a   id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:400e   id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ TOSHIBA Web Camera - FHD                  id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Toshiba input device                      id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Is there any other software missing to be able to configure touchpad and turn it on and off?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You should have `synclient`:

```
$ apropos synaptics
synaptics (4)        - touchpad input driver
synclient (1)        - commandline utility to query and modify Synaptics driver options.
```

See [`man synclient`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/synclient):
`synclient [-lV?] [var1=value1 [var2=value2] ...]`

For configuring the driver in `xorg.conf`, see [`man synaptics`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/synaptics).

Comment: `$ synclient -l`: Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?

Comment: Oh... I do not have a touchpad myself, so I do not know about the driver - but I added a hint to the answer.

Comment: K. Weber, you should consider checking the answer in case it solved your problem.